# using sklearn.utils.shuffle with images

Tags: python

I'm trying to use shuffle from sklearn.utils to shuffle 2 arrays at the same time but I think its not working. The shape of arrays:

```
    print( "class_image shape: ",class_image.shape)
    print( "class_label shape: ",class_label.shape)

class_image shape:  (550, 434, 636, 3)
class_label shape:  (550, 1)
```

and the shuffle code:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
 
class_image, class_label = shuffle(class_image, class_label , random_state=0)
```

after that, I notice the training is not working as before, I'm not sure if "shuffle" works if the array is multi-dim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just visualize a couple of images to see if it works and labels match, I tested with two random array, it is fine.

```
X = np.random.rand(2,2,2,3)
y = np.random.randint(100,size=2)
a,b = shuffle(X,y,random_state=0)
```

```
>>> X
array([[[[0.45317239, 0.71352665, 0.80314568],
         [0.29658996, 0.62204408, 0.24952528]],

        [[0.21216571, 0.39319804, 0.09277949],
         [0.5873337 , 0.1943893 , 0.69462845]]],


       [[[0.18323003, 0.60276493, 0.06357537],
         [0.54382163, 0.24957122, 0.86360364]],

        [[0.16123523, 0.02343267, 0.20177664],
         [0.96517567, 0.73551908, 0.06183611]]],


       [[[0.3355674 , 0.94292612, 0.08333506],
         [0.02070043, 0.65703864, 0.47144372]],

        [[0.47772838, 0.43128223, 0.44898601],
         [0.26247088, 0.54493139, 0.58774491]]]])
>>> y
array([41, 76, 79])
>>> a
array([[[[0.3355674 , 0.94292612, 0.08333506],
         [0.02070043, 0.65703864, 0.47144372]],

        [[0.47772838, 0.43128223, 0.44898601],
         [0.26247088, 0.54493139, 0.58774491]]],


       [[[0.18323003, 0.60276493, 0.06357537],
         [0.54382163, 0.24957122, 0.86360364]],

        [[0.16123523, 0.02343267, 0.20177664],
         [0.96517567, 0.73551908, 0.06183611]]],


       [[[0.45317239, 0.71352665, 0.80314568],
         [0.29658996, 0.62204408, 0.24952528]],

        [[0.21216571, 0.39319804, 0.09277949],
         [0.5873337 , 0.1943893 , 0.69462845]]]])
>>> b
array([79, 76, 41])
```

Comment: Thank you ..maybe I made a mistake in the tranning, not the shuffle.

Comment: @user836026 I suggest switching to pytorch, there are super handy tools, and there wont be any need to do these manually.